# Lookup to a column in a library having multiple hierarchical folder structure

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, document-library, lookup-column

I have a library A that has multiple folders and documents. I want to create a list B with a lookup column pointing to a column in Library A.

The problem I face is that the lookup column fetches only the first level (root level) information and not the files presented in sub folders.

What shall I do to get all the files present in the document library.

Comment: A lookup column isn't going to do what you want here. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? I get that you want to select a file, but for what? You may need a custom solution.

Comment: This would be a pointer to a document library where in users can view the document on click of Lookup column. Document library would be hidden from few set of users

Comment: You'll need custom code to get documents from subfolders. Try doing this with an application page inside of a grid.